# Type 'undefined' cannot be used as index type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am following WintellectNow React with TypeScript Tutorial. In the fifth part Sorting and filtering the author creates an interface with optional properties like below :

```
interface IWidgetToolState {
   filterCol?: WidgetTableCols;
   filterValue?: string;
   sortCol?: WidgetTableCols;
}
```

There is an enum called WidgetTableCols as below :

```
enum WidgetTableCols {
    None, Name, Color, Size, Quantity, Price,
}
```

In a function the author gets the value of enum like this :

```
const fName: string = 
WidgetTableCols[this.state.sortCol].toLocaleLowerCase();
```

Here I am getting Type `undefined` cannot be used as an index type. If I remove `?` from the interface it works but later the author creates another function that only sets one of the state values and TypeScript says not all of the state properties are set.

Can anybody let me know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using `strictNullChecks`?

Comment: Yes strictNullChecks is true. I changed it to false. Now its working.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The compiler just tells you that `this.state.sortCol` might not have a value because you have the `strictNullChecks` flag on.

You can first check for its existence:

```
const fName = this.state.sortCol != null ? 
WidgetTableCols[this.state.sortCol].toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
```

Which will remove the error (but you will then need to deal with the fact that `fName` can be null).

You can also use the [Non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
const fName: string = 
WidgetTableCols[this.state.sortCol!].toLocaleLowerCase();
```

If you're sure that it exists.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Will go with non null assertion operator.

Comment: Javascript allows undefined to be used as an index type. So the following works: x = {}; x[undefined] = 3; Why doesn't typescript allow it?

Comment: @Aaron in js keys of objects are **always** strings, when you're doing this `x[undefined] = 3;` you are basically getting this `x["undefined"] = 3;`. Typescript just forces you to acknowledge that.

Comment: Why would this situation occur even if you have strict checks beforehand? i.e. 
`if (this.state.sortCol && !!this.state.sortCol && etc..) WidgetTableCols[this.state.sortcol]` ?

Comment: Honestly I disagree with Typescript here. Undefined and null CAN be used as index, they just get cast to string. The same is true for numbers. For example `x[4] = 'something'` works just fine but here 4 is also cast to string and is the same as `x['4'] = 'something'`. I don't understand why it would be different for null and undefined.

Comment: When reading, seems like `object[undefined]` returns `undefined`. I'm wondering if there is a way in typescript to let me index by a potentially undefined value, and handle the potentially undefined return, instead of having to check for the value