# How do I tell TypeScript that you are guaranteed to have a valid return value in `find`?

Tags: typescript

ex:

```
const map = { small: 1, large: 2 };
const closestSize = ['small', 'large'].find((size) => !!map[size]); 

// errors Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538) but we know that either small or large will be found

return map[closestSize];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'undefined' cannot be used as index type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836274/type-undefined-cannot-be-used-as-index-type)

Comment: `map[closestSize!]` or `const closestSize = ['small', 'large'].find((size) => !!map[size])!; `

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir tried that and I'm getting `Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)`

Comment: @Toli Both versions work: https://typescript-play.js.org/?noImplicitAny=false#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAWwIYAc4F44G85WQG3wC44BGAGjnyQCcBzAUxICY4BfAblEljhHzBQGsAMoBLAF4MMcANoByPEkLzK86vQbyAugDoAZmIgATABSmokhgEoMAPjgBCR8hSzLU7dccc4wV7L8gsIw4p4cQA and  https://typescript-play.js.org/?noImplicitAny=false#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAWwIYAc4F44G85WQG3wC44BGAGjnyQCcBzAUxICY4BfAblEljhHzBQGsAMoBLAF4MMcANoByPEkLzK86vQbyAugDoAZmIgATABSmokhgEoMAPjgBCR8hSzLU7dY5xg+BvBgJBAArggARgw0Mq6y-ILCMOJSjtocQA You noticed the `!`, right ? I mention it beucasye it is easy to miss..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `find` function is:

```js
find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => boolean, thisArg?: any): T | undefined;
```

The signature says that the value can be undefined. If you want to tell the compiler that the value won't be undefined, just add `!` to the end:

```js
const closestSize = ['small', 'large'].find((size) => !!map[size])!;
```

or

```js
return map[closestSize]!;
```

Comment: Tried that and I'm getting `Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Solved it!! But with a slight edit. I have to do `return map[closestSize!]!;` Note the other `!` at the end which is to specify to the function signature that the map also returns a non-null