# how to render a specific field dynamically in Material Table React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

HI I am using Material Table of React, what I want to do is generate a label tag for every cell, what I did is:

```
            <Table
                onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                page={props.currentPage}
                totalCount={props.totalCount}
                options={{
                    paging:true,
                    pageSizeOptions:[10, 15, 25, 50],
                    pageSize: props.rowsPerPage,
                    padding: "dense",
                    search: false,
                    toolbar:false

                }}
                columns={columns.map((tableColumn) =>{
                    return{
                        ...tableColumn,
                        render: (rowData:VulnerabilityData) =>
                            (<label>
                                    {rowData[tableColumn.field]}. <---- error 'undefined'
                            </label>)
                    }
                })}
                data={vulnerabilityDataAct}

            />
```

In order to get the specific field, I passed in the `tableColumn.field` in the render,
but I got the error
**TS2538: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.**

I think tableColumn.field is not allowed here, **so how do I dynamically pass the tableColumn field and used as an index to render the value**???

Edit:
columns variables in above code:

```
const columns: TableColumn<VulnerabilityData>[] = [
    {
        title: 'Due Date',
        field: 'remediation_due_date',
    },
    {
        title: 'Application',
        field: 'primaryApplication'
    },
    {
        title: 'Impact',
        field: 'consequence'
    },
    {
        title: 'Mitigation',
        field: 'solution'
    },
    {
        title: 'CVE Description',
        field: 'cve_urls'
    },
    {
        title: 'Vulnerability Fix',
        field: 'vendor_urls'
    }
// and other 100 columns
];
```

and the definition of `VulnerabilityData`

```
export interface VulnerabilityData {

    primaryApplication: string;
    networkEnvironment: string;
    remediation_due_date: string,
  // ... other fields

}
```

Comment: Can you show `columns`?

Comment: @Viet thank you for reminding me. columns added

Answer (score 1):

The First thing is that you don't have to specify index numbers in the custom column rendering. In custom column rendering Material table provides single rowData for that specific talbe field. This means you're not required to specify index number Just use the `rowData.FieldName`. You can do it as follows

```
columns={[    
{ title: "Any Title", render: rowData => rowData.FieldYouWantToDisplay },
]}
```

Comment: I know we can do this, but what if I have 100 columns and all need `render`

Comment: and I want the `FieldYouWantToDisplay` to be dynamic, not hardcode on every field definition

Comment: If so column is a column it should be rendered under its own column. I don't think there will be a way to render 100 columns under one column. But you can render several rows dynamically.

Comment: can't we use `map` or something like that to dynamic render while looping thru columns??

Comment: I searched over the internet and found this. http://5.9.10.113/64490419/how-to-set-material-table-dynamic-columns-in-react-typescript It shows how to render dynamic column by using `map`

Answer (score 1):

Taking a shot at this. It looks like the error you are seeing here may be a typescript compiler error.

See this post: [Type 'undefined' cannot be used as index type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836274/type-undefined-cannot-be-used-as-index-type)

If it is a compiler error, you may fix it by explicitly defining the type of `tableColumns` in your `map` function. This type could be `{field: string}`, in order to let the typescript compiler know that `tableColumn.Field` will not be undefined.

You could also tackle this by setting a type on `columns` field before it is mapped.

Or you could also use `rowData[tableColumns.field!]`, as in the SO link.

I hope this solves your problem!